How can I force as much text as possible on the last line instead of the first line with CSS
I'm trying to create a product card that which has the title at the bottom. Sometimes the title is a bit longer and it needs to use two lines (it adds one at the top).
However it tries to fit as much text as possible on the first line, but I want as much text on the last line*
So I want this:
Standard behaviour
To be transformed to:
More text on the bottom line than on the top line
<div class="row-3-number">
  <div class="row-3-number-image">
    <div class="position-container position-container-3">3</div>
    <div class="row-3-number-gradient"></div>
    <span class="top-10-price top-10-old-price">€ 49,95</span>
    <span class="top-10-price">€ 38,95</span>
    <span class="row-3-number-title">Globe Whiskey Decanter</span>
    <img src="images\globe-decanter-hoofd_1.webp" alt="">
  </div>
  <p>Met deze indrukwekkende Globe Whiskey Decanter serveer je jouw favoriete  drankje in stijl.
    De glazen karaf heeft een luxe uitstraling een inhoud van maar liefst 0.9L!</p>
</div>

.top-10-price {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #fff;
}

.top-10-old-price {
    bottom: 50px;
    text-decoration: line-through;
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .70);
}
[..]
.row-3-number {
    width: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.row-3-number > p {
    margin: 20px;
}

.row-3-number-image {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.row-3-number-image > img {
    width: 350px;
    height: 350px;
}

.row-3-number-title {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    width: 230px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 20px;
}

I really prefer to do this without the use of php or javascript.
I've tried to use text-align-last but that only shifted the last line over without actually giving it all the text.
*The reason I want this is because I have placed a gradient from black to opaque at the bottom so the text is always readable. The text at the bottom is slightly more readable than the line above it.

AFAIK this is not possible dynamically.

I think you’d need a bit of JS.
